# Reverse lookup of variable values in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, debugging

I would like to be able, via a watch window, immediate window, or something else in Visual Studio 2005, to see every variable in my C# program that currently has a specific value.

Does Visual Studio have a way to "reverse lookup" and list all variables with a specific value, e.g. all strings currently in scope that equal "abc"?  Or is there a way to do this in code or the immediate window while debugging?

**Edit:** I left this comment on Oded's answer: The regular watch window won't do the trick. In short, due to the nature of my program's existing code and third-party APIs, I have to look in a lot of different places (and many levels deep) for exactly what is changing. What I'd like to know is whether I can do some sort of query (or find a tool that will) to say, "Show me every variable currently in scope that is a string equal to 'abc'."

Comment: I accepted Oded's answer today because I haven't gotten any answers on this question in a while.  If I get another answer (more related to the question) on this later, I may accept that one instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `watch` window. It holds the current values of the debugged methods.

There are several different [`variable` windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4dt5w8ta.aspx) in Visual Studio - they let you watch and change variables.

Comment: The regular watch window won't do the trick.  In short, due to the nature of my program's existing code and third-party APIs, I have to look in a lot of different places (and many levels deep) for exactly what is changing.  What I'd like to know is whether I can do some sort of query (or find a tool that will) to say, "Show me every variable currently in scope that is a string equal to 'abc'."

Comment: @David - Can you add this detail to your question? Your chances of getting better answer goes up the more relevant information you put in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you use the call stack window to navigate backwards in your code -once you have hit a break point, of course- you can check the value of each variable in its own context just moving the mouse over it.